# Clearinterval out of function scope does not work since the service is called several times

Tags: angular, typescript, setinterval, router

I got stuck on a problem which took my days and no expected result yet. I have a login component and authentication service. When I log in, the timer starts to pop up a modal after 30 seconds and after another 30 seconds it logs out. After login, if I log out before popup and log in again, the previous popup still appears. Please help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

login.component.ts

```
public async login(form: NgForm, event: Event) {
  this.auth.login(form.value.username, form.value.password).toPromise();
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
private count: number = 0;
private timerSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
private timer: Observable<number>;
private timeoutExpired: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
popupInterval: any;
timeLeft: number = 30;

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private notification: NotificationService
) { }

.
.
.

public startTimer(timeoutInMilliseconds: number) {
  if (!this.timerSubscription.closed) {
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  this.timer = Observable.timer(timeoutInMilliseconds);
  this.timerSubscription = this.timer.subscribe(n => {
      this.timeoutExpired.next(++this.count);
  });
}

.
.
.

public login(userid: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.api.post('/auth/login', {
    username: userid,
    password: password
  }, JsonApiService.HeaderJson).map((response: JsonResponse) => {
    if (this.timerSubscription.closed) {
      this.timerSubscription = new Subscription();
    }

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const token: Token = TypedJSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.json), 
    Token);


    // notify user about the end of the session which ends in five minutes
    this.startTimer(token.expirationDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime() - 30000);
    this.timerSubscription = this.timeoutExpired.subscribe(n => {

    let popupInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if(this.timeLeft == 0) {
        this.notification.dialog.closeAll();
        this.logout();
      } else {
        this.timeLeft--;
      }
    },1000)

    this.notification.notificationOkOnly(
      'Session Timeout',
      'Your session will expire in 1 minutes. Please finish your work in time.'
    )

  });

  return true;
  }).catch((err) => {
  {
     this.notification.notificationOkOnly('Login failed', 'login failed ');
  }

  return Observable.of(false)
  }).share();
}

.
.
.

public logout(): void {
  if (!this.timerSubscription.closed) {
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  clearInterval(this.popupInterval)
  Token.RemoveToken();
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little bit confused and it should be refactored, but I noticed that...

In your code you are setting a local variable `popupInterval`:

```
let popupInterval = setInterval(() => {
```

But the scope of this variable is only inside the login method. From other methods/functions you can't access to this variable.

For this reason that this line of the logout method doesn't make sense:

```
  clearInterval(this.popupInterval)
```

So... you should set the `popupInterval` as a class property:

```
this.popupInterval = setInterval(() => {
```

With this change, when you call the logout method, the `popupInterval` will be cleared correctly.